# Obtener datos no repetidos de una consulta con Streams en java

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

Tengo que realizar la siguiente actividad:

7.- showDifferentSubjectsOrderedAlphabetically()

Debe mostrar las asignaturas de las que hay algún alumno matriculado, ordenadas
alfabéticamente. La salida sería:
Asignaturas:
LM
PROGR

Para ello, he tenido que crear previamente diferentes clases, estas:

```java
package classes;

import java.util.List;

public class Student {

    private final long id;
    private final String name;
    private byte age;
    private String group;
    private int grant; // Beca.
    private List<Grade> grades; // Lista de notas.

    public Student(long id, String name, byte age, String group, int grant, Grade... grades) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.group = group;
        this.grant = grant;
        this.grades = List.of(grades);
    }

    /*
        Getters and Setters
     */
    public long getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public byte getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(byte age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public int getGrant() {
        return grant;
    }

    public void setGrant(int grant) {
        this.grant = grant;
    }

    public List<Grade> getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }

    public void setGrades(List<Grade> grades) {
        this.grades = grades;
    }
} // end class
```

```java
ackage classes;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Grade {

    private final String subject;
    private float mark;

    public Grade(String subject, float mark) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public float getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(float mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Grade grade = (Grade) o;
        return subject.equals(grade.subject);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(subject);
    }
} // end class
```

```java
package classes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database {

    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();


    public Database() {
        // ong id, String name, byte age, String group, int grant, Grade... grades
        students.add(new Student(1, "Germán Ginés", (byte) 23, "1o CFGS DAM", 2000, new Grade("PROGR", 8), new Grade("LM", 3)));
        students.add(new Student(2, "Baldomero", (byte) 21, "1o CFGS DAM", 0, new Grade("PROGR", 5), new Grade("LM", 4)));
        students.add(new Student(3, "Ana Guerra", (byte) 17, "1o CFGS SMR", 4000, new Grade("PROGR", 8)));

    }

    public List<Student> queryAllStudents() {
        return students;
    }
}
```

He intentado:

```java
public String[] showDifferentSubjectsOrderedAlphabetically() {
        return database.queryAllStudents().stream()
                .map(Student::getGrades)
    }
```

Y

```java
public String[] showDifferentSubjectsOrderedAlphabetically() {
        return database.queryAllStudents().stream()
                .flatMap(Student::getGrades)
    }
```

En la primera me devuelve un tipo super raro: Stream> y en la segunda me devuelve una lista de object... En cualquier de los dos casos, no puedo seguir.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Fijate aca https://stackify.com/streams-guide-java-8/  a ver si distinct te sirve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que map() es una operación intermedia, que devuelve otro Stream (ese tipo raro que dices que te aparece). Si quieres obtener un resultado que puedas manejar fácilmente, entonces agrégale una operacion terminal al final, por ejemplo:

```
        List<Grade> listGrades = database.queryAllStudents().stream()
            .flatMap(student -> student.getGrades().stream())
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Grade::getSubject))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Flatmap es necesario ya que getGrades retorna una lista de Grades, entonces necesitas "extraer" los elementos de esa lista, para que no quede una lista de listas. 
Además, necesitas ordenarlo por asignatura, y como bien te dijeron en el comentario, usar distinct() para eliminar los repetidos.

Comment: Mil gracias. ha funcionado perfectamente.