# Obtener "alumnos" y número de asignaturas en las que está matriculado Streams Java

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

Enlazo otra pregunta que hice, donde se ven todas las clases y datos con los que estoy trabajando.

[Obtener datos no repetidos de una consulta con Streams en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361887/obtener-datos-no-repetidos-de-una-consulta-con-streams-en-java)

Tengo que realizar la siguiente actividad:

19.- `showNumberOfSubjectsOfEachStudent()`

Debe mostrar el número de asignaturas de las que está matriculado cada alumnos. La salida
sería:

Número de asignaturas de cada alumno:
Baldomero: 2
Ana Guerra: 1
Germán Ginés: 2

He intentado, sin ningún éxito, esto:

```java
    public Map<String, Long> showNumberOfSubjectsOfEachStudent() {
        return database.queryAllStudents().parallelStream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName, Collectors.mapping(Student::getGrades, Collectors.counting())));
    }
```

Mi idea es obtener el nombre de los alumnos, aunque este dato podría estar repetido, así que creo que es mejor simplemente obtener el objeto alumno como tal, y luego obtener las materias y contarlas: la teoría muy bien, la práctica 0...

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Parecería estar bien, pero por qué usas parallelStream()? Hay que saber muy bien lo que se hace antes de usarlo, cambialo a stream() a ver que ocurre y luego seguimos investigando.

Comment: Lo he probado con stream y no ha cambiado nada. Realmente no creo que influya el hecho de usar parallelStream aquí. Creo que más vien, el problema está en que se me devuelve una lista, y cuento, no los elemento de dicha lista, sino la lista en sí... T-T. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que como getGrades() retorna una lista, si usas Collectors.mapping() obtienes un stream de listas, y cuando cuentas, es siempre 1 (porque es 1 stream por alummo que contiene muchas listas). 
Entonces tienes que usar Collectors.flatMapping(), para que todo devuelva una sola stream:

```
        Map<String, Long> map = database.queryAllStudents().stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName,
                            Collectors.flatMapping(student -> student.getGrades().stream(), Collectors.counting())));
```

Lo que te decía de parallelStream(), es que por un lado en muchos casos puede empeorar la performance, y por otro, dependiendo de los operadores, podría no devolver los resultados esperados.